# How to delete multiple data using entity framework and asp.net?

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, database, entity-framework

Hi I'm now learning about entity framework and still a beginner. Now, I've been having a problem with deleting multiple data in my database. Here is a piece of my database:

[Please click to see the image for database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C15KL.jpg)

For example i wanted to delete all data that has a brandId of 2. I tried using this code:

```
 int brandId = (from i in context.brands where i.name == name.Text select i.brandId).First();
var bay2 = (from g in context.logoes where brandId == g.brandId select g).FirstOrDefault();

        if (bay2 != null)
        {
            context.logoes.Remove(bay2);
            context.SaveChanges();
        }
```

But it only deletes one data, which is logoId 3. It did not delete logoId 4. What am i doing wrong in my query? How to delete all data that has brandId 2 using entity framework?

Comment: i believe you could remove multitple `logo` using `RemoveRange`..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This line is pulling only one object:

```
var bay2 = (from g in context.logoes where brandId == g.brandId select g).FirstOrDefault();
```

Because of the `FirstOrDefault`.

Remove the `FirstOrDefault`. Then use `RemoveRange`:

```
var bay2 = (from g in context.logoes where brandId == g.brandId select g).FirstOrDefault();

if (bay2.Any())
{
    context.logoes.RemoveRange(bay2);
    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use .ToList() method instead of First(). Then Iterate over this for example list using foreach and delete these objects, or delete whole range.